Euclidean domain question involving euclidean function and associates
Given R an euclidean domain with euclidean function f:R - {0} -> N, a and b non zero elements in R such that f(a) = f(b) and a divides b. Prove that a and b are associated.
What I got until now:
b = aq, for some q in R. Then f(aq) = f(b) = f(a).
My question is, from f(aq) = f(a), can I imply that f(q) = 1 then it is a unit?

Please use MathJax. Here is a
tutorial.
